# How do I place the index column name on the top row?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

The index name, 'brand' is not on the column header row. How can I change this?
Thanks !

```
brand__avg_price_series = pd.Series(brand_mean_price)
brand_avg_mileage_series = pd.Series(brand_mean_mileage)

df = pd.DataFrame(brand__avg_price_series,columns=['mean_price'])
df['mean_mileage(km)'] = brand_avg_mileage_series
df.index.name = 'brand'

       |mean_price| mean_mileage|
brand  |          |
renault| 99999    | 9999
```

Comment: Please provide sample data to reproduce your input and expected output dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reset_index`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

This will move the index into a column.